# Unable to upvote comments when reviewing close votes

Tags: bug, feature-request, review, closing

Whenever I am reviewing the close votes on the main site, I often (perhaps always) encounter the issue that I am unable to upvote comments to the question from the review screen, but have to open up the question in a separate tab. I am still able to add new comments, but often someone has said all that needs to be said. I don't like casting close votes unless it is clear to the asker why I have done this, so I like to make sure that I upvote any relevant comments, which gets quite annoying when I have to open tabs for several questions in a row.

Is anyone else having this issue? I am running chrome on windows seven if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like it was designed that way.  Aside from complaining to each other, nobody here can do anything; it'd need to be raised at [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).  And it was raised:

- [Allow voting on comments from Review interface](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146783)

See also:

- [Allow comment upvoting in review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149318)
- [Enable voting up comments in all review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164652)
- [Upvote comments in 'Reopen votes' queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171714)

It has decent support, but no official response has been made yet.